# Using positive voltage reference on a negative supply

Tags: voltage-reference

Got a 9V,0,-9V power supply and want to get two stabilised voltage references at 2.5V and -2.5V.

Is it possible to use a +2.5V reference chip "upside down" to supply the -2.5V?

Comment: Shunt, not series, references, no problem. Or just use an op-amp and a matched resistor network to get -2.5V.

Answer (score 3):

You could invert a +2.5 volt reference to -2.5 volts using an op-amp but I'd simply use a +2.5 volt shunt reference device like this one: -

[image]

And re-position is in the "negative circuit" like this: -

[image]

There are eighty-four +2.5 volt shunt references listed [here on Mouser](https://www.mouser.co.uk/Power/Power-Management-ICs/Voltage-References/_/N-6g7lz?P=1z0wa2kZ1yx1uxs) so I expect you'll be able to find one that is suitable in terms of accuracy and drift.

Note that the DS for the LM336 states on page 1: -

> Further, since the LM136-
>   2.5 operates as a shunt regulator, it can be used as either a positive or negative voltage reference.

This applies to any shunt voltage reference of course.